# Хочу найти заголовок при парсиге с помощью селениум

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Вот мой код, он простой

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
user=UserAgent()
profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override',user.random)
driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get('https://rabota.ykt.ru/')
```

Это изменение юзерагента

```
vacansii=driver.find_element_by_class_name('r-vacancy r-vacancy--vip r-vacancy--paid')
spisok=vacansii.find_element_by_class_name('r-vacancy_title')
print(spisok.text())
```

Я не понимаю, почему не работает?

```
File "E:\Python\rabota\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "E:\Python\rabota\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "E:\Python\rabota\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\Python\rabota\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .r-vacancy r-vacancy--vip r-vacancy--paid
```

Вот код ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Это связано с тем, что в качестве агрумента `find_element_by_class_name` вы указываете список классов вместо одного класса. Чтобы избавиться от этой ошибки советую вам использовать css селекторы (метод `find_element_by_css_selector`)
Современные браузеры должны предоставлять возможность скопировать CSS селектор нужного элемента. Firefox точно даёт такую возможность.

Вторым способом решения проблемы может выбор всех элементов, содержащих первый класс, из них выбрать те, которые содержат второй класс и так далее.
Это некрасивый и неэффективный способ.